# IONIC - background image not showing with apk

Tags: android, image, ionic-framework, apk, device

I'm my html page I have a ion-content with the class **getstart**, with a background image, placed in **assets/img**.
It works perfectly into the web browser, but wen I test the app with the apk, the background remains white.

I know that It's a recurrent question, but all the answers that I found (in this and other sites) don't work for me.

This is my scss code, placed inside **app.scss**

```
  .getstart{
    background: url('../assets/img/venice.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

  }
```

I tried changing che image url like '**/assets/img/venice.jpg**' , but nothing worked.

I'm really stuck :( 
Thank you in advance!

**SOLVED:** Silly mistake. My background image was venice.JPG and not .jpg so the apk didn't recognize any image. I changed my extension's file an all worked.
Thank for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be correct, just as you already tried the link "assets/img/venice.jpg".

Did you inspect your device via chrome? maybe the picture si missing there.
Try to change the name of the picture. No idea why but this helped my once.

Comment: I solved it, it was a silly mistake. I didn’t know that the apk it’s case sensitive. My image was a .JPG and in the url I write .jpg so the apk didn't recognize any image.

Comment: Thanks mate, @felix and @ JEricaM, I used both solutions, :-), case sensitive naming and also path...

Answer (score -1):

every thing is perfect but i thing this would the best try to use this

```
enter code here background: url(../../assets/imgs/Login.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```